# How to reduced length of code ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to calculate total page number, based on total number of days.
Example: 0 to 25 days page 1,
         26 to 50 days page 2 etc…!
I am using below method.

```
df$totalpage <- ifelse(df$days >=0 & df$days<=25,1,
                      ifelse(df$days >=26 & df$days<=50,2,"Something wrong"))
```

Is there any other method to do the same, as if I have more days (> 365 ) I have to add many ifelse which makes code lengthy. any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: See `?cut` or `?findInterval`

Comment: But i have only one row data(name of data frame is ```df```).means single value of days..!

Comment: Does `findInterval(df$days, seq(0,365,25))` work?

Comment: Yes,working fine.Thank you so much..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `findInterval`

```
findInterval(df$days, seq(0,365,25))
```

Or `cut`

```
cut(df$days, seq(0,365,25), labels = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, which only needs `ceiling()` and division `/`

```
df$totalpage <- ceiling(df$days/25))
```